# Will the JaxB object factory populate default values to mandatory elements

Tags: java, jaxb

We are using the ObjectFactory class to create objects to marshal it xml file. Will the ObjectFactory class populate default values to mandatory elements when we create a new object.

In XSD:

```
element name="MerchantCategoryCode" default="5541
```

Java:

```
ObjectFactory ob = new ObjectFactory();
MyObject myOb  = ob.createMyObject();
myOb.getMerchantCategoryCode(); // giving null value
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from: [Elements Default Value and Marshalling](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Element_default_values_and_marshalling.html)
When a class has an element property with the default value, and if a value is null, then the marshaller will not produce the corresponding element in XML.

```
@XmlRootElement
class Product {
  @XmlElement(defaultValue="Apple") public String modelName=null;
}

 marshaller.marshal(new Product(),System.out);
```

> Output of above will be: <product />

Element defaults do not comes into picture when the element is absent, which is correct as per XSD.

If you want the above value to contain a default value just assign it at java level like below:

```
 @XmlRootElement
class Product {
  @XmlElement public String modelName="Apple";
}


marshaller.marshal(new Product(),System.out);
```

Output of above is:

> <product>
>       <modelName>Apple
>       </product>